# how dose pthread implement thread cancellation, which system call it used?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, signals

I know that if a thread is PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, then it can be canceled, and  `pthread_cancel(pthread_t thread)` will send a cancellation request to the specified thread, and the reaction of the thread depend on the following 2 attributes:

- if the cancellation type is PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, cancellation requests are acted on immediately.
- if the cancellation type is PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, cancellation requests are acted on as soon as the thread reaches a cancellation point.

I just want to know what happened at the cancellation point and in the signal handler, and how it can respond to the cancellation request at the cancellation point. I know pthreads use signals to implement this, but I do not know the details. This problem bothered me for a long time!!!

Wish you guys could help me, thanks a lot for your answers!!!

Comment: Pthreads is a *specification*.  There is no "how pthreads does X" in any general sense, only how specific implementations of pthreads do things.

Comment: But even if you were to designate a specific implementation in which you were interested, the question is pretty broad, and I'm not seeing a lot of use for an answer.  Especially given that the #1 rule of `pthread_cancel()` is "never call `pthread_cancel()`".